# Content.js not firing

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm attempting a super basic 'hello world' chrome extension.
I want a content script to interact with the browser's page.
There are no errors present but no console log from the content.js.

I've tried Google's documentation here:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

And have watched this guy here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Tl3OmwrSaM&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6bL9VOMT65ahNEri9uqLWfS&index=3

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Hello World",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "xxxxx",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "images/icon128.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ]
}
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="js/Main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
      button {
        height: 30px;
        width: 300px;
        outline: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="btnTest">TEST</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

content.js

```
console.log("CONTENT!");
```

Any ideas?

Comment: When you change manifest.json or a content script you need to 1) click the reload circle icon in chrome://extensions page and 2) reload the web page (s).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the comment encouraging you to reload the extension after each update, make sure you are not testing this extension on the extensions page itself (`chrome://extensions/`). Try something like `www.google.com`. You can't inject content into the `chrome://extensions/` page.